# How to open mdDialog in a custom directive from ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, mddialog

I'm trying to get ng-click in a template to open a modal in a custom directive while sending some form parameters to the diretives controller and then call a service. I have it in a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NgGeX2mVkzvEfqh1TaWZ?p=preview), but I can't get to the directive apparently from the ng-click.

I thought I could just use $scope and not isolated scope for this, but I'm not sure of the correct structure for something like this.  I have to try and make all this a component, so that is why I'm using a custom directive.

I've seen lots of somewhat similar things, but not exactly what I'm trying to do.  Any ideas as to the correct structure on how to do this and what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is the code I have so far:

**index.html**

```
  <head>
    <link data-require="angular_material_design@0.6.1" data-semver="0.6.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.6.1/angular-material.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular_material_design@0.6.1" data-semver="0.6.1" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/hammerjs/2.0.4/hammer.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular_material_design@0.6.1" data-semver="0.6.1" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular_material_design@0.6.1" data-semver="0.6.1" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular_material_design@0.6.1" data-semver="0.6.1" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular_material_design@0.6.1" data-semver="0.6.1" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.6.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-directive></my-directive>
    <div align="center">
      <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="openLogin()">Login</md-button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**myDialog**

```
<md-dialog>
    <md-toolbar class="md-primary">
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools" layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
            <h2 class="md-flex">Login</h2>

            <md-button class="md-icon-button md-accent md-hue-2" aria-label="Close" ng-click="closeDialog()">
                <md-icon md-primary md-svg-icon="assets/images/ic_close_24px.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>

        </div>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-content class="sticky-container">
        <div class="dialog-content">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">Username:</label>
              <input type="text" id="username" ng-model="login.username">

            <label for="password">Password:</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" ng-model="login.password">
          <br><br>

          <div>
                    <md-button id="btnCancel" class="input-lg md-raised md-accent" type="cancel" flex>Cancel</md-button>
                    <md-button id="btnSubmit" class="input-lg md-raised md-accent" type="submit" ng-submit="submit(login)" flex>Login</md-button>
                </div>

        </div>
    </md-content>
</md-dialog>
```

**script.js**

```
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: loginController,
      template: '<div></div>'
    };

    loginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$mdDialog'];

        function loginController($scope, $mdDialog) {

         $scope.openDialog = function(){
          $mdDialog.show({
            controller: function($scope, $mdDialog){
              // do something with dialog scope
              console.log("username is: " + $scope.username);
              console.log("password is: " + $scope.password);
              //TODO Call service function to authenticate.
            },
          templateUrl: 'myDialog.html'
        });
          }
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include material design in the app like so:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngMaterial']);
```

You need to have a controller attached like so:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
```

To open modal no need for strange directive behaviour you can just open from the controller, however if you really want directive here is a working one (also included in plunker)

```
app.directive('myDirective', ['$rootScope', '$mdDialog', function($rootScope, $mdDialog){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    template: '<md-button ng-click="openLogin()" class="md-raised md-primary">Login(Directive)</md-button>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, model) {
      scope.openLogin = function(){
        var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();
        $mdDialog.show({
          scope: modalScope,
          templateUrl: 'myDialog.html',
          clickOutsideToClose: true,
          parent: angular.element(document.body),
        }).then(function (result) {
          //result contains username and password
        }, function(){
          //modal exited/cancelled
        });
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/hfxyWHidbB19PU5p3k9Z?p=preview

Comment: Actually what I'm doing is more complicated than my plunker, but this helps!  I missed the obvious material design library too!  Thanks Tim!